# WooCommerce - admin-ajax.php still needs a lot of time - how to dequeue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

I have a performance issue with my website currently. I can see the following chart:

[image]

I added the following code to my functions.php in order to only enqueue WooCommerce styles and scripts on the shop pages:

```
function grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner() {

    // Remove the generator tag
    remove_action( 'wp_head', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce'], 'generator' ) );
    // Unless we're in the store, remove all the cruft!
    if ( ! is_woocommerce() && ! is_cart() && ! is_checkout() ) {
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_frontend_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-general');
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-layout' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce-smallscreen' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_fancybox_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_chosen_styles' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'woocommerce_prettyPhoto_css' );
        wp_dequeue_style( 'select2' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-payment-method' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-lost-password' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc_price_slider' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart-fragments' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-credit-card-form' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-single-product' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-cart' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-chosen' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'woocommerce' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'prettyPhoto-init' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-blockui' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-placeholder' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-payment' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'fancybox' );
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jqueryui' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'grd_woocommerce_script_cleaner', 99 );
```

However I can still see these styles / scripts to be enqueued:

plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js?ver=2.70
plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/woocommerce.min.js?ver=2.4.12

**Inline:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var woocommerce_params = {"ajax_url":"\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php","wc_ajax_url":"\/?wc-ajax=%%endpoint%%"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Does anybody know how I can check which plugins are calling admin-ajax.php 5 times in total and how I can dequeue the other woocommerce scripts/styles?

Thank you!

Comment: Try concatenating scripts/styles with Gulp or Grunt as part of some production build script. You shouldn't have this many disparate files for a production build.

Comment: @staypuftman How can I do this in a productive environment including all plugins etc?

Comment: I'd have to know a lot about your setup. In general, I usually put my gulp file in the root of my theme and concatenate assets there. With woocommerce you might have to have the build script bunch together additional assets. The idea is that you run the build script pre-push and it minifies and combines them all together - that would fix having all these calls at least but might not fix all perf issues.